# Сгруппировать блоки по нумерации

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день!

Есть 3 блока и у каждого есть свой номер, который может меняться (от 1 до 3)
Грубо говоря это выглядит так:

```
var block1_number = 1;
var block1 = '<div>text</div>';

var block2_number = 3;
var block2 = '<div>text</div>';

var block3_number = 2;
var block3 = '<div>text</div>';
```

К примеру если у `block3_number` будет номер 1, то `block3` он должен поменяться местами с `block1`

Можно делать так:

```
$.fn.swap = function(b){

        b = $(b)[0];
        var a = this[0],
            a2 = a.cloneNode(true),
            b2 = b.cloneNode(true),
            stack = this;

        a.parentNode.replaceChild(b2, a);
        b.parentNode.replaceChild(a2, b);

        stack[0] = a2;
        return this.pushStack( stack );

    };

if(block3_number < block1_number){
 $(block3).swap(block1);
}
```

Но получается нужно прописывать все условия, можно ли упростить задачу? Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: положите в масивы, и используйте цикл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имхо, лучше использовать массив и хранить позицию вместе с самим элементом:

```js
var blocks = [{
  position: 1,
  dom: $("<div>Block 1</div>")
}, {
  position: 4,
  dom: $("<div>Block 4</div>")
}, {
  position: 3,
  dom: $("<div>Block 3</div>")
}, {
  position: 2,
  dom: $("<div>Block 2</div>")
}];

function sort() {
  blocks = blocks.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.position > b.position
  });
  blocks.forEach(function(b) {
    $("main").append(b.dom);
  });
}
// вставляем в исходном порядке
blocks.forEach(function(b) {
  $("main").append(b.dom);
});
// сортируем и перевставляем
setTimeout(sort, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main></main>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var blocks_number = [1, 2, 3];
var blocks = ['<div>text</div>', '<div>text</div>', '<div>text</div>'];
```

И потом:

```
for (var i = 0, l = blocks_number.length; i < l; i++) {
    for (var j = blocks_number.length - 1, l = 0; i >= l; i--) {
        if (i === j)
         continue;
        if(blocks_number[j] < blocks_number[i]){
            $(block[j]).swap(blocks[i]);
    }
}
```

**NB!** Код только демонстрирует принцип. Возможны коллизии.